# Insert image (file or R object) into existing html file from R script

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, htmltools

I include two ggplotly() graphics in a html file, eg.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

g1 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
g2 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=11:20, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
l1 <- ggplotly(g1)
l2 <- ggplotly(g2)

htmltools::save_html(htmltools::tagList(l1,l2), file ="index.html")
```

And now want to include an image in the same html file,eg a ggplot2 object:

```
foto <- imresize(load.image(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")),0.25)
fotodf <- as.data.frame(foto,wide="c") %>% mutate(rgb.val=rgb(c.1,c.2,c.3))
p <- ggplot(fotodf,aes(x,y))+geom_raster(aes(fill=rgb.val)) + scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_fixed() + theme_void()
```

or insert the image file into the html file directly.
The problem is that I do not find how to insert either the p ggplot object
or the logo.tif file into index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

g1 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
g2 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=11:20, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
l1 <- ggplotly(g1)
l2 <- ggplotly(g2)

# the ggplot graphs
html_file <- htmltools::tagList(l1, l2)

image_path <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/1920px-R_logo.svg.png"
# or any image in the www folder
html_image <- tags$img(
  src = image_path, 
  alt = "image", 
  width = "100px", 
  height = "100px", 
  style = "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;"
)
# ggplot graphs with 
html_file_with_image <- htmltools::tagList(html_file, html_image)
htmltools::save_html(html_file_with_image, file = "index.html")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks, extremely useful.
As I need the image to be another graphic rather than an overlay (using the logo is just for an example), I've modified your code to:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

g1 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
g2 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=11:20, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
g3 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=21:30, y=1:10)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
l1 <- ggplotly(g1)
l2 <- ggplotly(g2)
l3 <- ggplotly(g3)

image_path <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/1920px-R_logo.svg.png"

html_image <- tags$img(
  src = image_path, 
  alt = "image",
  style = "position: float:center;width:25%;")

html_file <- htmltools::tagList(div(l1, style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
                                div(l2, style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
                                div(l3, style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
                                html_image)
htmltools::save_html(html_file, file = "index.html")
```

which results into:

[image]

I'd appreciate a link to doc on the actual "style" definitions. I still get the image left-aligned while I try to put it at the center of its quadrant.